# Uncaught TypeError: Vue.use is not a function

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am relatively new to VueJS, and now I am trying to replace the

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

The problem is that previoulsy working code got broken after this change:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const defaultOptions = {
            position: 'bottom-center'
        }
        Vue.use(Toasted, defaultOptions) # The error arises here
    });

</script>
```

I am running into

> Uncaught TypeError: Vue.use is not a function

What am I doing wrong here ?

UPDATE:
I am not using webpack for now. Is it possible to do that without webpack ?

Comment: use this https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6 instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@next` refers to vue 3 which has different a different syntax, by assuming that `Toasted` plugin is compatible with vue 3 you should do :

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const defaultOptions = {
            position: 'bottom-center'
        }
        Vue.createApp({}).use(Toasted, defaultOptions) 
    });

</script>
```